# Reading records from a file separated by tabs

Tags: c

Input file:

```
Joe Smith    10 Main St.    555-1212
```

I'm reading a record from a file that has the above format which contains 3 fields, name address and phone number separated by tabs.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s", rec[size].name, rec[size].address, rec[size].phone_number) != EOF)
{
    size++;
}
```

I have to include the white space for the first word and ignore the tabs and start reading the next field.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Note that you should be checking `while (fscanf(fp, …) == 3)` since that will tell you if there was a problem with only two fields left in the file.  Also note that `fscanf()` is of limited use for line-oriented input — it doesn't care where the newlines appear, and would be happy with the information spread over three lines.  Use `fgets()` or `getline()` and then `sscanf()` to parse lines of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char buffer[4096];
int n;

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != 0)
{
    if ((n = sscanf(buffer, "%[^\t] %[^\t] %[^\t\n]",
        rec[size].name, rec[size].address, rec[size].phone_number)) != 3)
    {
        if (n != EOF)
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: faulty record without 3 fields at:\n%s",
                    buffer);
        break;
    }
    size++;
}
```

Note that this uses `fgets()` to read lines.  It checks that `sscanf()` read three fields.  You should not get `n == EOF`, but test just in case.  The error message is reported on standard error, and includes the line that caused the trouble (one of the major advantages of `fgets()` plus `sscanf()` is that you have the line captured for retries or error reporting).